# Calling endpoint results in HTTP 440 ProtocolException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webapi

I have an endpoint in my webapplication that I'm trying to test by executing a request with Postman.
However when I execute a request this results in an HTTP 440 (that's not a typo) which had never heard of can't find much about on what it actually entails or what causes it.

The console shows the following log:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action MyWebApplication.Controllers.MyController.Get (MyWebApplication) in 19.3113ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
      Executed endpoint 'MyWebApplication.Controllers.MyController.Get (MyWebApplication)'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5001/api/v3/my - - - 440 0 - 817.4851ms
```

The information above tells me that the endpoint can be found.
The breakpoint in the controller does get hit but the breakpoint in the endpoint doesn't.

Comment: It means `440 Login Time-out
The client's session has expired and must log in again` do you have something related to session?

Comment: Do you need to change HTTP 1.1 (chunk mode) to HTTP 1.0 (stream mode) or maybe HTTP 2.0, or to HTTPS (secure).